# Subquery MySQL Syntax err

Tags: mysql

I an newbie in MySql.I have a query

```
SELECT `UserName` as muser
     , month(date) as month
     , year(date) as year
     , sum(select (`en_status`) (case when leave=2 en_status=1/2 else leave=1 en_status=0 else enstatus=1 end)) as present
     , 
 group 
    by user_id
```

here i got an error from sub query.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select (`en_status`) (case when leave=2, en_status=1/2 end)) as present,sum(`...' at line 1

Any help would be appreciated.

Please help me.

Comment: There's lots wrong here. Why don't we just start over?

Comment: Yep. Err is so much better than roor

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT  `UserName` as muser
        , MONTH(date) as month
        , YEAR(date) as year
        , SUM(CASE WHEN leave=2 THEN 0.5 WHEN leave=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as present

FROM    YourTableName

GROUP BY    `UserName`
            ,MONTH(date)
            ,YEAR(date)
```

Please let me know if it solved your issue, or if it needs some adjustments